# How can I add on Orders list in the back office of the Prestahop 1.6 a new column for Company?

Tags: php, sql, overriding, prestashop

I'm using a website with 1.6.1.7 Prestashop's version and I want to show on Orders page, between Customer and Total columns, a new column for customer's Company. I prefer, if it is possible, overriding the necessary file.

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspaX.png)

Could someone help me to do that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the B2B option in PrestaShop, the company will be displayed in the orders list without override.

Anyway this is how to add a column in an existing controller by overriding its class.

```
<?php
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // add the field to the SQL query
        $this->_select .= ', c.company as company';

        // field to insert
        $insert = array(
            'company' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Company'),
                'filter_key' => 'c!company',
            )
        );

        // splice the fields list
        $end = array_splice($this->fields_list, array_search("customer", array_keys($this->fields_list)));
        // insert the new field
        $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, $insert, $end);
    }
}
```